# undefined method `blog_path' in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to change an existing project from sqlite3 base to postgresql base and I got this one last error that I don't know how to solve.

The blog_path in the following html file launches an undefined method 'blog_path' error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Blog</title>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Blogs</h1>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="left-block">
            </div>
            <div class="blog-container">
                <% @blogs = @blogs.reverse %>
                <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
                    <div class="blog">
                        <p class="title"><%= blog.title %></p>
                        <p class="time"><%= blog.created_at %></p>
                        <%= link_to 'Learn More', blog_path(blog), class: "btn btn-info" %>
                    </div>
                <% end %>
            </div>
            <div class="right-block">
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <%= link_to 'New Blog', '/blogs/new', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is Blog class

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
end
```

This is the route.rb in config folder

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  get '/blogs' => 'blogs#index'
  get '/blogs/new' => 'blogs#new'
  post '/blogs' => 'blogs#create'
  get '/blogs/:id' => 'blogs#show'
  get '/blogs/:id/edit' => 'blogs#edit'
  patch '/blogs/:id' => 'blogs#update'
  delete '/blogs/:id' => 'blogs#destroy'
end
```

This is blogs_controller.rb

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @blogs = Blog.all
    end

    def new
        @blog = Blog.new
    end

    def create
        @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)
        if @blog.save
            redirect_to blogs_url
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def show
        @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
        @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
        @blog.update_attributes(blog_params)

        redirect_to blogs_url
    end

    def destroy
        @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
        @blog.destroy
        redirect_to blogs_url
    end

    private
        def blog_params
            params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :content)
        end

end
```

**Please let me know if any other resources are needed for solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `resources :blogs` in routes file instead of defining each and every route independently

More here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thank you so much! It fixes it. 

Then this is kinda extra stuff to ask, but if I want to set the url to be 'signup' for 'users#index', I need to explicitly specify it, am I right?